# Datatable jump to page which contains tr with certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to use `row().show()` plugin to jump to page where is `tr` with class `.scrollAndHightlight` in my DataTable with id `#reqToApp`.

Here is my DT initialization with initComplete function:

```
var table = $('#reqToApp').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    stateSave: true,
    fixedHeader: true,
    autoWidth: false,
    select: true,
    order: [[1, "desc"]],
    "iDisplayLength": 15,
    language: {
        "url": "/js/Czech.json"
    },
    "aoColumns": [
        {"bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": true, "sType": "html"},
        {"bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": true, "sType": "string"},
        {"bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": true, "sType": "string"},
        {"bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": true, "sType": "string"},
        {"bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": true, "sType": "string"},
        {"bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": true, "sType": "string"},
        {"bVisible": true, "bSortable": true, "bSearchable": true, "sType": "string"},
        {"bVisible": true, "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false, "sType": "html"}
    ],
    "initComplete": function(settings, json){
        var row = table.row($(".scrollAndHighlight")).node();
        table.row(row).draw().show().draw(false);
    }
});
```

But it does nothing, no errors in console.

What am I doing wrong?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/2427/

Comment: AFAIK `row().show()` is a DataTable plugin. Have you added the script?

Comment: A quick look into the documentation shows that `table.row(row).draw().show().draw(false)` is the correct usage of the function.

Comment: Wait, is that datatable's `initComplete`?

Comment: Yes it is datatable's. Is it wrong?

Comment: Are you using server-side processing and is row with that class on another page?

Comment: No I dont and yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `$()` jQuery method because it has access to elements that exists in DOM only. With jQuery DataTables pages other than current don't exist in DOM, therefore row on pages other than first couldn't be found.

You can supply CSS selector to `row()` method instead.

For example:

```
"initComplete": function(settings, json){
   var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
   var row = api.row(".scrollAndHighlight").node();
   api.row(row).draw().show().draw(false);
}
```

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/2433/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: for me it fails in last line, error "api.row(...).draw(...).show is not a function"

Comment: @MoslemCherif, you need to include files for [row().show()](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/row().show()) plug-in.